# Nested scrolling and AdapterView

Tags: android, android-view, android-adapterview, android-viewgroup

I want to implement Material nested scrolling for my adapter that `extends AdapterView`.

The problem is `AdapterView` supports `setNestedScrollingEnabled` only from API 21 and my minimum is 15. There are `ViewGroupCompat` and even `AdapterViewCompat`, that could in theory help me re-implement my adapter with something like `extends AdapterViewCompat`, but they are unusable as `AdapterViewCompat` is internal and `ViewGroupCompat` is... `final`(why?!)

Stealmate? Or is there a solution?

OK, so... more details.

Since I am using a (X,Y) instead of standard linear adapter, it was convenient to create a better interface (there can be different number of X's per each Y's, so...):

```
public interface MatrixAdapterInterface extends Adapter {
    int getRowCount();

    int getColCount(int row);

    Object getItem(int row, int col);

    View getView(int row, int col, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);

    boolean isEmpty();
}
```

This of course required an `AdapterView` that is able to handle (X,Y) indexing (by mapping (X,Y) to linear nature of `ViewGroup`), not worth listing in whole here:

```
public abstract class MatrixAdapter<T extends MatrixAdapterInterface>
        extends AdapterView<T> {
     ....   
}
```

And finally the layout that uses this `AdapterView` and that doesn't pass any nested scroll events:

```
public class XenoMatrixLayout extends
        MatrixAdapter<SomeMatrixAdapterInterface implementation> {

}
```

Now... touch handling is a bit complex... First there's:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean handled = onTouchEvent(ev);
    if (handled)
        return true;
    if (ev.getPointerCount() == 2)
        processDoubleTouchEvent(ev);
    handled = mGesture.onTouchEvent(ev);

    return handled;
}
```

Then there're:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (mFastScroller != null) {
        boolean intercepted = mFastScroller.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        if (intercepted) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (mFastScroller != null) {
        boolean intercepted = mFastScroller.onTouchEvent(ev);
        if (intercepted) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Anything more you need to know?

Answer (score 1):

I answered your previous similar question; since you gave some more details here, I will add to my earlier answer:

Your custom adapter view will implement the `NestedScrollingChild` interface from the support library.  This will allow it to work with classes like `CoordinatorLayout`, even on pre-Lollipop devices.  When the nested scrolling methods require a method on the view parent, the `ViewCompat` class will call the existing view method on Lollipop & later, and call the static `ViewCompat` methods for KitKat and earlier, where these methods don't exist.

So when you delegate to the helper class, it does the heavy lifting of figuring out which platform it's on and which methods it must call.

If you are extending `AdapterView` then you must have done all your own scroll event handling by overriding `onTouchEvent()`. That gives you the opportunity to use these methods.  If you need more help, please post your code and we can try to help you more specifically.

Comment: Let me try and work it out. I'll give more details if I'm hopelessly stuck! Thanks for both answers! OK, maybe I'll do it now...